# Re compiling ubuntu kernel

Tags: kernel

I wanted to re-compile my kernel with some changes. Is it possible to make the necessary changes and  retain ubuntu updaes for my kernel?

Thanks,
Digvijay

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit and redefine your question. The way in which it is written is confusing and may not receive any answers.

Comment: What changes do you need to make? If it's a single kernel module that needs a small change which is compatible with Ubuntu' kernel, you can use DKMS to keep it updated with each kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

In case you compile your own kernel it won't be possible for you to automatically receive upgrades, and still retain your modifications.

If you really need a modified kernel my suggestion would be to clone the appropriate Ubuntu git kernel repo. That way, whenever there are important (security) upgrades available, you can merge those changes with your local modifications, and build a new kernel from that.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide for info on available repositories.